# Reference docs for Azure Resource Templates

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I am looking for reference docs for the Azure Resource Manager JSON templates. Does anyone know if there is reference material for these templates?

There is general reference for required parameters etc like at [Create a template deployment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790564.aspx).

I am basically looking for the full availability so I can correspond setup on the portal to the JSON template. Also availability of features with apiVersion releases. I remember there being a MSDN documentation for the changelog with api version releases but cannot find it now.

Comment: Related: https://disqus.com/home/discussion/windowsazureblog/iaas_just_got_easier_again/#comment-2021471923

Comment: Microsoft recently add this to the ARM docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/ - Expand the References for each resource type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft has finally created what I was looking for : full documentation is now available at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/templates/

Comment: Seems to missing lots of stuff like app services, functionapps for example

Answer (score 4):

If you create a VM with the desired settings, extensions etc then you can view their json template via https://resources.azure.com/

This will give some visibility into the Classic* templates.

Comment: Thanks for this link! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

All of the ARM templates can be found on GitHub here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas.

It includes preview templates and should provide all the information you're after to determine which features are present in which apiVersion release.

Comment: just seeing that it's a not so optimal question that excerted this not so optimal answer ;-)

Comment: This seems to be the clearest way I've seen so far to browse the available specs. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

After some digging I managed to get the following list of schemas:

- http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json
- http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-06-01/Microsoft.Web.json
- http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/Microsoft.Sql.json
- http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01/Microsoft.Insights.json
- http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-02-26/microsoft.visualstudio.json
- http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/Microsoft.Cache.json
- http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01/Microsoft.BizTalkServices.json
- http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-08-01/Microsoft.Scheduler.json
- http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01/SuccessBricks.ClearDB.json
- http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/Microsoft.Resources.json
- http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/Microsoft.Authorization.json
- http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-10-01-preview/Microsoft.Authorization.json

This list notably excludes:

- Microsoft.ClassicCompute
- Microsoft.ClassicStorage
- Microsoft.ClassicNetwork

So I guess we're left to figure stuff out from the templates on those

Comment: I have edited the answer given by @D-side to include some resource I found after Build 2015 announcements. QuickStart templates http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/templates/ and blog on Iaas templates you mentioned are missing http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/04/29/iaas-just-got-easier-again/

Answer (score 2):

To my mind we can dig that way:

- open the [azure-resource-manager schemas](https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas/blob/master/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json)
- Look at the main form below:
  [image]
- If you open properties, you will find the format that we need to fill:
  [image]
- open parameters and look at the structure: 
  [image]
- `$ref: #/definitions/parameter` invite us to look at the same documents in `definitions.parameters` where you will find some documentation (like value you can use etc):

[image]

- finally, if you look to `properties.resources`, you will find a list of url like:

  - { "$ref": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-07-01-preview/Microsoft.ServerManagement.json#/resourceDefinitions/node" }
  - { "$ref": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-07-01-preview/Microsoft.ServerManagement.json#/resourceDefinitions/gateway" }
- if you open one of these url, you will find the JSON format you are looking for (here is a part of the first one):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is not much available...

**Azure Resource Manager Template Language**
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authoring-templates/

And then you can look at the different json.schemas that I have managed to find

**deploymentTemplate**
http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json

**visualstudio**
http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-02-26/microsoft.visualstudio.json

**Sql**
http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-06-01/2014-04-01-preview/Microsoft.Sql.json

**Web**
http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-06-01/Microsoft.Web.json

**deploymentParameters**
http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentParameters.json

If you use Visual Studio to edit the json-template file you get intellisense (sometimes) which help a bit. But the lack of documentation is really annoying...for example I have no clue if the schemas listed above are the most recent or not, and I have no idea where to find which one is the most resent.

**Edit:**
I came across [the list of additions and changes to the Service Management APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg592580.aspx). Seems to be a bit outdated, `2015-01-01` is the current version and it's not there.

**Edit2:**
With the Iaas updates at Build 2015, there seems to also be a lot of [Azure Quickstart Templates](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/templates/). At minimum, they have the particular cases I was looking for with storage accounts.

Comment: Sadly this about all I came up with as well so far

Comment: its like ms dont want us to use their products or something :) when you lookup webjobs sdk documentation you get a getting started guide (on scott h's blog) which has a whole lot of outdated beta references. AWS dont release stuff without documentation to go with it, not sure why MS believes they can do different.

Comment: It seems like Microsoft no longer document their stuff. At most you can find a blog post or a "click guide" if you are lucky.  Basic documentation like where you go to find out the latest version of a schema, which schemas are available and how do they really work on a deeper more technical level is nowhere to be found. Doing more complicated stuff then what is covered in the mostly useless sales inspired click guides from the market department is a huge struggle. Time is spent to just figure out the most basic things like the datatype of a parameter, or if you are running the latest version.